# Function 'findSmallerDigits' should return an array of numbers of smaller digits JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, digits

Write a countNextSmaller function that accepts an array of numbers and returns a new array of numbers, the i-th element of which must be the number of numbers to the right of numbers[i] that are smaller than numbers[i].

This is my code:

```
function countNextSmaller(numbers) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) {
      arr.push(numbers[i + 1]);
    } else {
      arr.push(0);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

I think this can be implemented using the filter function, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate over the elements to the right of the current one. While you can use `.filter`, `.reduce` would arguably be more appropriate because you need to know *how many* are smaller (a number), not *which ones* are smaller (an array).

```js
const countNextSmaller = numbers => numbers.map(
  (number, i) => numbers.slice(i).reduce(
    (a, b) => a + (b < number),
    0
  )
);
console.log(countNextSmaller([1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 2]));
```